# How can I preserve /tmp across reboots?

Tags: mojave

Simply, I want /tmp (/private/tmp) to not vanish if the system is rebooted. (Yes, really.)

It doesn't appear to be mounted to a special file system, so there's something occurring during startup.

I'm running Mojave at the moment.

Comment: `/tmp` is purposely designed not to survive a reboot. If you need to write something to disk that can survive a reboot then write it elsewhere.

Comment: I know what it's designed for. I have a different design.

Comment: Can you describe your design? - Why not write to any other location than /tmp?

Comment: Would copying the contents of elsewhere on shutdown and copying them back on startup work for you?

Comment: Why not use /var/tmp?

Comment: Honestly, I don't want to editorialize why I want this done. I just want it done. Let the daily cleaners do their job, but not restart.